# Higher order inline functions, and MDCContext

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, slf4j, mdc, structured-logging

So I'm trying to write a higher order function that adds Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) to a closure that is passed as parameter.

There are two ways to make it work. One for non suspending functions (`MDC.put`) and one for suspending functions (`MDCContext`)... But is there a way to make it work in any kind of functions?

I know there's no "suspending variance", other than using the `inline` modifier, yet...

Just curious!

Comment: Why not use `inline`, though? It's quite useful for higher-order functions anyway, and you get the free benefit of being able to pass suspending lambdas

Comment: @Joffrey, because the only way to use MDCContext is with withContext, and that's a suspend function. So I basically cannot use it in non suspending functions